Unit Testing Mocking Object For EF.Property<T>
I have a method in a generic class which uses an expression tree to provide the property name that it should use to match when querying the database for existing records.
public virtual List<TEntity> GetExistingRecords(HashSet<TKey> sourceKeys)
{
    var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)KeySelector().Body).Member.Name;

    return _targetDbContext.Set<TEntity>()
        .Where(e => sourceKeys.Contains(EF.Property<TKey>(e, propertyName)))
        .ToList();
}

Here is the expression implemented in the derived class:
protected override Expression<Func<AccountEntity, long>> KeySelector() => accountEntity => accountEntity.AccountNumber;

It works well, except when mocking it in my unit tests:
public class CustomerServiceTests
{
  private readonly Mock<WriteDbContext> _mockCustomerDbContext;
  private readonly Mock<StagingDbContext> _mockStagingDbContext;
  private readonly Mock<IMapper> _mockMapper;
  private readonly Core.Concrete.Domain.CustomerService _customerService;

  public CustomerServiceTests()
  {
      _mockCustomerDbContext = new Mock<WriteDbContext>();
      _mockStagingDbContext = new Mock<StagingDbContext>();
      _mockMapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
      _customerService = new Core.Concrete.Domain.CustomerService(_mockStagingDbContext.Object, _mockCustomerDbContext.Object, _mockMapper.Object);
  }

  [Fact]
  public async Task MigrateAccounts_ShouldAddNewAccounts()
  {
      // Arrange
      var sourceAccounts = CustomerTestData.GenerateAccounts(1);
      var sourceAccountEntities = CustomerTestData.GenerateAccountEntities(1);
      var existingAccounts = new List<AccountEntity>().AsQueryable();

      _mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<List<Account>>(It.IsAny<List<AccountDto>>())).Returns(sourceAccounts);
      _mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<List<AccountEntity>>(It.IsAny<List<Account>>())).Returns(sourceAccountEntities);
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Setup(db => db.Set<AccountEntity>()).ReturnsDbSet(existingAccounts);
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Setup(db => db.Set<AccountEntity>().AddRangeAsync(It.IsAny<List<AccountEntity>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Setup(db => db.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(1);

      // Act
      await _customerService.MigrateAccounts();

      // Assert
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Verify(db => db.Set<AccountEntity>().AddRangeAsync(It.Is<List<AccountEntity>>(entities => entities.Count == 1), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Verify(db => db.Set<AccountEntity>().UpdateRange(It.IsAny<List<AccountEntity>>()), Times.Never);
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Verify(db => db.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
  }

  [Fact]
  public async Task MigrateAccounts_ShouldUpdateExistingAccounts()
  {
      // Arrange
      var sourceAccounts = CustomerTestData.GenerateAccounts(1);
      var existingAccounts = CustomerTestData.GenerateAccountEntities(1).AsQueryable();

      _mockMapper.Setup(m => m.Map<List<Account>>(It.IsAny<List<AccountDto>>())).Returns(sourceAccounts);
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Setup(db => db.Set<AccountEntity>()).ReturnsDbSet(existingAccounts);
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Setup(db => db.Set<AccountEntity>().UpdateRange(It.IsAny<List<AccountEntity>>()));
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Setup(db => db.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(1);
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Setup(db => db.ReplaceEntity(It.IsAny<AccountEntity>(), It.IsAny<AccountEntity>()));

      // Act
      await _customerService.MigrateAccounts();

      // Assert
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Verify(db => db.Set<AccountEntity>().AddRangeAsync(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<AccountEntity>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Never);
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Verify(db => db.Set<AccountEntity>().UpdateRange(It.Is<List<AccountEntity>>(entities => entities.Count == 1)), Times.Once);
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Verify(db => db.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
      _mockCustomerDbContext.Verify(db => db.ReplaceEntity(It.IsAny<AccountEntity>(), It.IsAny<AccountEntity>()), Times.Exactly(1));
  }

The first test passes, I assume because there is no iteration happening, but for the second and third they both fail with a System.InvalidOperationException : The EF.Property<T> method may only be used within Entity Framework LINQ queries. error within the DBContext method call in GetExistingRecords.
Can anyone shed some light on how I should setup my mocking differently to correct this?
Edit: I have added a DotNetFiddle to show the error with a condensed version of the structure of my code here - https://dotnetfiddle.net/CQTYc4. If you change line 84 to return emptyEntities instead then there is no exception thrown.

DON'T try to mock the DbContext at all. You don't work in the EF Core team so you don't need to test parts of EF itself work in isolation. Create a DbContext with the in-memory provider or SQLite in in-memory mode instead.

The code here doesn't test the service, it tests the mock setup. Even if the setup works. verifying that SaveChanges was called doesn't say the AccountEntity rows were created or modified, so it's pointless. BTW AddRangeAsync isn't needed in 99.999999999% of cases, because Add doesn't add anything to the database, it starts tracking a detached entity in the Added state. That's a local CPU operation, nothing more. It's SaveChanges that saves all pending operations.

And since you don't use the conventional Id field, you do need to verify that entities are loaded and saved correctly. .Where(e => sourceKeys.Contains(e.Id) gets translated to WHERE ID IN (@id1, @id2,@id3...) so the type of sourceKeys doesn't matter as long as it's an IEnumerable that can be iterated to get all values. That's the only reason HashSet works, although it's slower to iterate. If you load entities with EF to modify them, you don't need Update at all, EF already knows they were modified.

PS: What's the purpose of GetExistingRecords anyway? The entire method tries to do what _context.Set<Customers>().Where(c=>ids.Contains(c.Id)).ToList() would do. Even if there was a reason to extract this one-liner into a method, you could create a truly generic method either on the DbContext itself or as an extension method, that accepts the entity with a type constraint TEntity:IHasId where the interface is just interface IHasId { long Id {get;}}

A truly generic method would be eg public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetByIds<TEntity>(IEnumerable<long> ids) where TEntity:IHasId =>this.Set<TEntity>().Where(e=>ids.Contains(e.Id)); or as an extension method, public static IEnumerable<TEntity> GetByIds<TEntity>(this DbContext context,IEnumerable<long> ids) where TEntity:IHasId =>context.Set<TEntity>().Where(e=>ids.Contains(e.Id));. You can push things farther by making IHasId generic too, but frankly, I fail to see the benefit in any of this. It looks like you're trying to recover the abstractions lost by a fake repository antipattern
